# How to create an array of Controls with different types i.e Textbox, combobox, checkbox...based on certain value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox, textbox, controls

VB.net how to create an array of Controls with different types i.e Textbox, combobox, checkbox...based on certain value

This is the code:

```
Public Function TestControl(c As Integer())
        Dim a As Control()
        Dim l As Point
        Dim F As New Form
        For i As Integer = 0 To c.Length - 1
            If c(i) Then
                a(i) = New TextBox
            Else
                a(i) = New ComboBox
            End If
            a(i).Width = 400
            a(i).Height = 40
            l.Y = 50 + (3 * i - 2) * a(i).Height / 2
            l.X = 150
            a(i).Location = l
            F.Controls.Add(a(i))
        Next
        F.Show()
        Return Nothing
   End Function
```

When I am trying to execute the Function the following Error appears:

***Variable 'a' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.***

I am trying to solve it but i couldn't succeed.
any Idea would very helpful for me

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Why do you want to do this?  They are already in one or another controls collection.  Lumping them together as `Control` means you wont know which have a `Checked` property and which have a `SelectedIndex` property etc

Comment: well this the Idea that I want implement it:    I have different datables under a dataset. whenever i want add row to a table i am calling a new form with textboxes, Combobox, checkbox...depending of type of column ...than on closing the form I will get the data from those controls to update my table,

Comment: If that's what you want to, what makes you think you can't do it? `Dim ctrl As Control()` declares an array that will hold any object that is  a Control, or a class that inherits from Control.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [tour].

Comment: 'For i As Integer = 0 To c.Length - 1
            If c(i) Then
                ctrl(i) = New TextBox
            Else
                ctrl(i) = New ComboBox
            End If        
            ctrl(i).Location = l
            F.Controls.Add(ctrl(i))
       Next'     Where c is an array of array of 0 and 1....when i run it, it gave me error saying to check if ctrl is not null

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45425716/edit) your question to add the relevant code and a full description of the error. For guidelines see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please turn `Option Strict On`.  You have some issues with your code.  For instance, this line:  `If c(i) Then` doesn't make sense because `c` is not an array of `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your immediate probem of "Variable 'a' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

Your problem is that the line

```
Dim a As Control()
```

only creates a variable `a` that is capable of holding an array of control objects. It doesnt actually create an array, because it doesn't know how many elements to create.

In your situation the solution is straightforward. Change the line to

```
Dim a(c.Length) As Control
```

This will create an empty array of controls that you can add your TextBoxes and ComboBoxes.

Comment: David, you are 100% right and that works perfectly. Thanks